# Secure data on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

We are developing windows mobile application (using c language). We storing application data folder as xml files. How can protect data folder so noone can directly access (from File Explorer) and modify it? Can we make data folder password protected?

Please suggest....

Answer (score 0):

Storing data at client side is a very big issue that too in clear text. So, if you are planning to store the data in XML files or SQLite files, please encrypt those with good encryption algorithm.
Because WhatsApp is encrypted using MD5 algorithm and 196-bit key also broken by hackers. You can find more details on this [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-whatsapp-chat-forensic-analysis/).

So becareful while storing the data on device.